# Where to place custom Css for Bridge theme in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Anyone using Bridge theme in wordpress? Please let me know where to set custom Css which will work for all pages. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and add your custom CSS there.

Comment: I got my answer, Qode options=>general=> at the buttom you can find option for custum css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer of my asked question

```
Qode options=>General=>
```

at the buttom of this page you can find the option for adding custom css
[image]