# Position sticky doesn't work in wordpress (Bridge theme) but works in codepen

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox, sticky

I gave the container and the sticky item the following CSS:

```
.sticky-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.sticky-item {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

I have tried adding height to the container and `overflow:visible` to both items. Everything works great in `codepen` but doesn't work on my WordPress website. Any idea why?

It's probably worth mentioning get a message in the wordpress css editor saying "Expected ( Static | Relative | Absolute | Fixed ) but found sticky"

Comment: It could be a lot of things. Have you checked in browser inspector are rules of your .sticky-item class applied to the element that you wanted?

Comment: [Here's a picture of the inspector](https://ibb.co/gUrYN9)

Answer (score 0):

As Lazar said in the comments, could be alot of things. Have you tried setting a z-index on the sticky-item? Might be that it is attaching but you can't see it because it is hidden by something with a higher z-index.

Edit:

Are you sure your theme are including the style.css for your theme?

eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/style.css">
```

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work. It's probably worth mentioning get a message in the wordpress css editor saying "Expected ( Static | Relative | Absolute | Fixed ) but found sticky"

Comment: @JohnHolliday I tried adding sticky on a wordpress site and it worked even though I got that warning too.

Comment: @JohnHolliday Did you see my edit in the answer above?

Comment: @JohnHolliday Also, did some digging in the Bridge-theme. Where are you trying to add the custom css? Looks like there is a plugin included in the theme called Qode where you do just that. See the answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822127/where-to-place-custom-css-for-bridge-theme-in-wordpress

Comment: Thank you again, man! I just tried adding it there too, so far I was using the standard place for most themes under Appearance > Customize > Custom CSS. Unfortunately no luck with that either. The theme uses VC and i think that's the problem. It puts my container in a container row and a column, maybe those parent elements are creating the discrepancy somehow. I tried adding overflow:visible to all css selectors i saw between the sitcky container and the row ,but i had no luck

Comment: Ah well, my Sherlock adventure ends here unfortunately. Hope you find a solution!

Comment: I appreciate all the time you took! I'll update the post if I find the solution